# Elasticseach, sort on cross datefields

Tags: elasticsearch

In my elasticsearch-index, if I have records that looks something like this:

```
{
    "date1":  "<someDate>",
    "date2":   "<someOtherDate>"
}
```

Is it possible to make a query that gives me the documents in order accross the "date1" and "data2" fields?

For instance, if I have these records:

```
1: {"date1": "1950-01-01",
    "date2": "2000-01-01"}

2:  {"date1": "1960-01-01",
     "date2": "1951-01-01"}

3:  {"date1": "1970-01-01",
     "date2": "1950-02-02"}
```

The order I want to receive them in should be 1,3,2 because 1 has the the earliest date in the date1 field, then 3 has the next one in the date2 field, and then 2 in the date2 field.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably illustrate what you need using a few examples.

Comment: Changed the syntax and added example added to make what I need more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ElasticSearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html), you have two options:

1. sort using array using [Sort mode option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_sort_mode_option)
2. sort using custom [sorting script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting)

### 1. Sorting using array

The first option requires that you change your mapping and put documents like this:

```
PUT /my_index/my_type/1
{"date1": ["1950-01-01", "2000-01-01"]}
```

Then you will be able to make a query like this:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "sort" : [
        { "date1" : {"order" : "asc", "mode": "min"}}
    ]
}
```

### 2. Sorting using custom script

The second option is to write a sorting script, and it works with your document structure. Here is an example:

```
GET /my_index2/_search
{
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "inline": 
"if (doc['date1'].value < doc['date2'].value) { doc['date1'].value } else { doc['date2'].value} ",
                "params" : {
                    "factor" : 1.1
                }
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

The scripting language that is suggested to use is called [painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html).

### Discussion

Which one to choose is up to you. Performance can be a problem with scripting option, also `painless` scripting was introduced only in ES 5 (In [ES 2.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-scripting.html) the closest equivalent was Groovy, which was not enabled by default as it's dangerous). Sorting using arrays should be faster, since it's a built-in feature, but requires to store data differently.